# Как правильно обработать ответ Json?

Tags: android, json, retrofit2

`введите сюда код`Вот то что отправляю на сервер :

```
"device_id":"a40d38a959f1ca65"
```

Вот ответ который должен быть:

```
    "personnel":[
      {
         "personnel_number":444,
         "first_name":"Иван",
         "last_name":"mts",
         "middle_name":"",
         "id":1012651
      },
      {
         "personnel_number":777,
         "first_name":"Василий",
         "last_name":"mts1",
         "middle_name":"",
         "id":1012652
      }
   ],
   "success":true


List<Post> posts = Collections.singletonList(response.body());
                Iterator itr = posts.iterator();

                while(itr.hasNext()) {
                    post = (Post) itr.next();
                    Log.e("asd", "yes " + post.getId());
                }
```

Comment: в вашем случае будет возвращаться в качестве ответа PersonnelArray где будет список, уточните что именно не получается

Comment: Да! Все верно! Но мне нужно отдельно вытащить значения personnel_number, first_name и т д! Все что у меня получается это взять все одним списком

Comment: так пройдитесь циклом по списку и возьмите отдельно, или вам код цикла нужен?

Comment: Мне нужно это сделать через getter, в дальнейшем нужно вынимать отдельное значение на пример longitude и  latitude и указывать это на карте

Comment: ну так сделайте) у вас будет response.getBody().getPersonnels() и это уже будет ваш массив

Comment: Наверно я уже запарился совсем! Покажите что Вы имеете ввиду! Просто получается что если по циклу брать и по позициям, я вынимаю ситроку на данной позиций! Там где у меня и name и id и вся строка

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему у вас в модели перед массивом стоит `@SerializedName("personnel_number")`?  брать из json список с таким ключем не получится поэтому и null я думаю, так же вам стоит учитывать что в массиве есть объекты, которые вы не обрабатываете никак. По логике вам нужно что-то типа такого:

```
class PersonnelArray{

    @SerializedName("personnel")
    private List<PersonnelValue> personnels;

    public List<PersonnelValue> getPersonnels() {
        return personnels;
    }
}
```

и модель человека:

```
class PersonnelValue{
    @SerializedName("personnel_number")
    @Expose
    private String perNum;
    ....

    public void setPersonnelNumber(Integer personnelNumber) {
          this.personnelNumber = personnelNumber;
     }


    public Integer getPersonnelNumber() {
       return personnelNumber;
     }

}
```

а вы все поля впихнули в один класс-модель, что немного противоречит вашему json. Дальше вы сможете получить список и пройтись по нему в цикле. [Вот есть хороший туториал](https://dds861.medium.com/json-arrays-parsing-using-retrofit-and-recycleview-9b2d494cc24c) по работе с json массивами надеюсь пригодится.

### UPDATE

Вот например как пройтись циклом:

```
List myEmpls = new ArrayList();
Iterator itr = myEmpls.iterator();

while(itr.hasNext()) {   
    PersonnelValue pobj = (PersonnelValue) itr.next();
    System.out.println(pobj .getPersonnelNumber());
}
```

*P.S. Метка android-studio должна использоваться в вопросах связанных непосредственно с IDE. Просьба это учитывать в дальнейших вопросах.*

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131312/discussion-on-answer-by-andrew-----json).